# Configuración SSL dominio .CL (Angular - Heroku - Amazon Route 53)

Tags: java, angular, ssl, heroku, amazon

Tengo una aplicación que cuenta con un backend JAVA con framework Spring Boot y frontend en Angular 6. Todo esto alojado en Heroku. Requiero configurar con SSL el dominio .cl. Utilizamos Route 53 como servicio DNS pero tenemos problemas al ingresar con www ya que en ese caso despliega el sitio pero sin https. Habilitamos SSL en Heroku, probamos en la configuración de Angular en el archivo server.js pero no hemos podido solucionar esto ¿Alguna recomendación para solucionar esto?

> Esta es la configuración del archivo server.js

```
//Install express server
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

// Use the /dist directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/app-frontend'));

//HTTPS redirect middleware
function ensureSecure(req, res, next) {
    //Heroku stores the origin protocol in a header variable. The app itself is isolated within the dyno and all request objects have an HTTP protocol.
    if (req.get('X-Forwarded-Proto') == 'https' || req.hostname == 'localhost') {
        //Serve Angular App by passing control to the next middleware
        next();
    } else if (req.get('X-Forwarded-Proto') != 'https' && req.get('X-Forwarded-Port') != '443') {
        //Redirect if not HTTP with original request URL
        res.redirect('https://' + req.hostname + req.url);
    }
}

app.use(ensureSecure);

// Catch all other invalid routes
app.all('*', function (req, res) {
    res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/app-frontend/index.html');
});

// Start the app by listening on the default Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```